# What should I learn to be able to transform expression in Java to another expression (like interpreter does)?

Tags: java, parsing

The idea is simple - for example I want to tranform every expression in code like

```
if(isTrue())
  doThis();
else
  doThat();
```

Into

```
isTrue() ? doThis() : doThat();
```

How should I approach this problem? Which concepts should I be familiar with?

P.S. I understand that ternary operator isn't working like that and other stuff about it, it's just an example. I want to understand how should I approach parsing Java expression problems and what I have to learn to be able to understand the solution for this problem.

Comment: what did you mean, just do it !

Comment: It is not at all clear what your question is. Do you want to write a program that parses and modifies source code, or are you asking how to do that within your IDE? And hint: most likely, most people would say: using the ?: operator to express if/else like that is **bad practice**. ?: is **less** readable than if/else!

Comment: Read about parse trees and syntax lowering. If your aim is to build this program then you need to start with a parser that can understand most Java syntax

Comment: @GhostCat for starters I want to understand how parsing programming languages expressions works. After that I'd like to know how could such functionality be implemented in IDE (like in Intellij Idea).

Comment: @CarsonMyers So are there any usefull links where I can start? Or just Googling "parse trees" and "syntax lowering" will work?

Comment: Oh man. **Whole** books are written about such topics. If you are really interested in this topic, go search for "compiler construction". As said; this is way too broad for a single question/answer on SO.

Comment: @GhostCat I guess anwer like "Learn about compiler construction. Good books are $book1, $book2 and some usefull links are $link1, $link2" is really broad answer, you are right :) SO is really weird, I will never understand it... But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Asking for such recommendations is fully off topic here. Simple as that. Documented all over the place. There is nothing mysterious about that.

Comment: @FalAlexandr But as you are serious about your answers: if you really want to understand how this community ticks ... spend some time at the help center; or on META. We have rules and policies here; and all of that is documented. And another hint: being a software person means: having *intrinsic* curiosity. In 2017 you don't need other people to recommend books. Use a search engine, compare reviews, things. The point is: asking other people for explanations can be helpful; but it should not be your first option. Always collect information yourself, first. Hope that helps ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat the problems starts when you don't know what exactly should you search for. Where should I ask how can I find RELEVANT information about programming concept? I asked concrete question about concrete concept in concrete language. You pointed out how this concept is called and what I have to search for. That was question about specific problem I tried to Google first. It is directly related to writing computer programs. Which part of SO policy have I violated? :)

Comment: @FalAlexandr Dragon book is where I started with compilers: https://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-2nd/dp/0321486811

Comment: @carson Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I'd learn is something about the syntax of the Java language. You can find details [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

You can *never* convert something into this form:

```
isTrue() ? doThis() : doThat();
```

because the [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) is not a [`StatementExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression).

This means that you can't make it into a statement via the addition of a semicolon like you can with other expression types (e.g. method invocation, incrementing variables, new class creation). Conditional operators can only be used inside other expressions or statements.

As such, this is simply invalid syntax.

---

*Provided `doThis()` and `doThat()` aren't `void`*, you can abuse syntax to use the conditional operator. For instance, if they both return `boolean`, you can write:

```
if (isTrue() ? doThis() : doThat()) {}
```

or if they return reference types, you can do:

```
Object unusedVariable = isTrue() ? doThis() : doThat();
```

But these are simply gross.

Leave it as a conditional statement, it's much easier to read.

Comment: So I can't write a Java program which will find every expression in first form and transform it into the second form? By transform I mean just rewrite it. The question isn't about how do make the ternary operator work like it works in C++, it's about how to approach parsing programming language expressions. Maybe the example wasn't rally good, but honestly I couldn't make up something better... But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You should take a look at [Google's errorprone](http://errorprone.info), and probably more specifically at [Refaster](http://errorprone.info/docs/refaster), which is example-based refactoring. It almost certainly does what you want. My answer was pointing out that you have to have a good understanding of what it is you're actually trying to manipulate first.

Comment: What I'm trying to manipulate is Java expressions :) And what I need is some theory behind parsing and manipulating programming langueges expressions. But and actual implementation of such tool will be useful as well, thank you very much!